# Add data labels to each segment in column stacked chart

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code to generate a `chart` for me based on values passed in from a previous portion of this `macro`.

```
    Set graph2 = graphSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=200, Top:=200, Width:=450, Height:=300)

    graph2.Chart.ChartWizard graphSheet.Range("A1:C5"), gallery:=xlColumnStacked, PlotBy:=xlColumns, serieslabels:=1, _
                         HasLegend:=True, Title:="Cumulative Operating Portfolio", categorytitle:="Year", _
                         valuetitle:="MW_dc", categorylabels:=1
```

It works fine, however, I would like to add numeric `data labels` to each segment of the stacked graph.  I tried the following code to see if I could get any part of the way there:

```
    With graph2.SeriesCollection(1)
        .HasDataLabels -True
        .DataLabels.NumberFormat = "####.##"
    End With
```

This does not work, and it is not surprising as I am not too knowledgeable about the `property`.  How can I add in data labels?

Comment: Is `graph2` defined as `ChartObject` ? I think you have a Typo, it should be `.HasDataLabels = True` and not `.HasDataLabels -True`

Comment: Oh that is rather embarrassing. Thank you for the syntax catch.  Graph2 is defined as a `ChartObject`.  I updated to add that initialization in.

Comment: Or perhaps I should clarify and say as a `ChartObjects`. Unsure if these are different, and if so, how different they are (`ChartObject` vs `ChartObjects`)

Comment: so it;s working now ?

Comment: No. The above does not work. I get the object does not support... error.

Answer (score 0):

The `SeriesCollection` ia a member of the `Chart` properties, and not the `ChartObject`.

```
ChartObject
   |
   > Chart
       |       
       > SeriesCollection
```

So for your above code to work use the code below:

```
With graph2.Chart.SeriesCollection(1)
    .HasDataLabels = True
    .DataLabels.NumberFormat = "####.##"
End With
```